# sequenceInputLayer() Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, lstm, seq2seq

I try to create an LSTM model. I get following error:

> Error using vertcat Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not
>   consistent. Error in source (line 9)
>       sequenceInputLayer(33)

What should be the input of `sequenceInputLayer` and its size?

```matlab
Data = csvread('newData.csv');
num_timesteps = size(Data,1)
num_features = size(Data,2)
Data = normalize(Data);
numHiddenUnits = 200;
size(Data)
layers = [
    sequenceInputLayer(33)
    lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits,'OutputMode','sequence')
    fullyConnectedLayer(50)
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    fullyConnectedLayer(num_features),regressionLayer];
maxEpochs = 60;
miniBatchSize = 20;
options = trainingOptions('adam', ...
    'MaxEpochs',maxEpochs, ...
    'MiniBatchSize',miniBatchSize, ...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.001, ...
    'GradientThreshold',1, ...
    'Shuffle','never', ...
    'Plots','training-progress',...
    'Verbose',0);
% net = trainNetwork(Data,Data,layers,options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in `sequenceInputLayer`, the problem is in the way you are creating the `layers` array.

Replace:

```matlab
layers = [
    sequenceInputLayer(33)
    lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits,'OutputMode','sequence')
    fullyConnectedLayer(50)
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    fullyConnectedLayer(num_features),regressionLayer];
```

With:

```matlab
layers = [
    sequenceInputLayer(33)
    lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits,'OutputMode','sequence')
    fullyConnectedLayer(50)
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    fullyConnectedLayer(num_features),
    regressionLayer];
```

**Explanation:** In an array declaration, when adding elements in new lines (or separating by `;`) you are crating a columns vector, when separating by `,`, you are crating a row vector. Somehow you mixed them up.